# Why doesn't my wi-fi router send STP frames?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, tcpdump

I'm learning about Spanning Tree Protocol and was trying to capture STP frames sent from my wi-fi router by tcpdump. Here is the command:

```
sudo tcpdump -vv -n -i en0 stp
```

and for pretty large period of time I haven't noticed any STP frames printed out. Does it mean the my router doesn't send `BPDU`s and therefore does not support bridging?

Comment: There's nothing to suggest you have a bridge at all

Comment: And anyway: using STP is to avoid a loop between multiple bridges. As a standard (consumer-grade) Wifi AP doesn't allow to use a bridge on the STAtion client (this would require [4 MAC addresses mode / 4A / WDS](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header) instead of the Wifi default of 3 (and instead of Ethernet's 2)), STP becomes useless here. Don't do Ethernet experiments on Wifi.

Comment: @A.B In fact my intention was to create a bridge between a wireless network and a tap ethernet network interface. This does not seem to be possible, do it?

Comment: If you're experimenting, use Ethernet, including virtual Ethernet between VMs (btw, due to a longstanding bug/oversight in Linux still present today, don't experiment STP and loops with *containers*, only use *VMs*). If your goal is about Wireless, you need an AP where you can use hostapd and configure it yourself (the client too needs special setup, not just the AP)